# Convert LP3 parameters following a unit change

Tags: distributions, modeling, units

The USGS uses a Log Pearson Type 3 (LP3) distribution to model flood frequency based on cubic feet per second (cfs) annual maximum flow data (AMAX). The result for a gauging station is the three parameters mu, sigma, and gamma (mean, sd, and skew).

I have many sets of these values. However, it is usual to express river flow in units of meters cubed per second (cumecs). The conversion factor is 1 cfs = 0.028 cumecs.

Is it possible to convert the LP3 parameters to the equivalent that would have been identified had the AMAX data been expressed in cumecs rather than cfs?